# Symbolic link and sudo

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, symbolic-link

I create a symbolic link:

`ln -s /tmp/folder1 /tmp/folder2`

Then I go to /tmp/folder2 and run `pwd`:

```
$ cd /tmp/folder2/
$ pwd
/tmp/folder2
$ sudo pwd
/tmp/folder1 # <-- This is the odd part
```

**Why does `pwd` with `sudo` give the original directory?** I'm writing a bash script and need the absolute path of the current directory. With sudo I can't seem to be able to get the original directory.

Comment: Is your goal to have pwd return the physical (/tmp/folder1) path or the logical (/tmp/folder2) path for both ?

Comment: Goal is to return the logical path when using sudo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [pwd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pwd) command is both a shell builtin and /bin/pwd. Under normal circumstances, the builtin will be run in preference to /bin/pwd. The pwd command can be called as `pwd -L` or `pwd -P` Both the builtin and /bin/pwd default to `pwd -L` from the man page

> -L, --logical
>                 use PWD from environment, even if it contains symlinks

so when you run pwd you actually run pwd -L which in effect prints $PWD (if it exists). When you run `sudo pwd`, sudo only provides the environment variables that is has been told to pass on via `env_keep` directives. PWD is not normally in this list so sudo pwd has to work out where it is and in effect runs as `pwd -P`

> -P, --physical
>                 avoid all symlinks

The way to solve the problem is to either use `pwd -P` if you consistently want the physical directory path or (as @Felix says ) to add PWD to the list of environment variables to keep via an env_keep directive in sudoers

```
env_keep += "PWD"
```

Comment: Works! After PWD is added to env_keep I need to do `sudo pwd -L` to get the logical path. `sudo pwd` returns the physical path.

Answer (score 6):

In bash, `pwd` is a builtin. `/bin/pwd` yields the same behavior as `sudo pwd`.

You will want to

1. use `sudo pwd -L`, which only works if you
2. include `Defaults env_keep=PWD` in your `sudoers` file